# Anyway to get a Palm Pilot (Tungsten E2) to sync with evolution or thunderbird?

Tags: sync, pim

any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a USB cable connector for it?

Comment: Yes I do, I also have a blue tooth dongle too...

Comment: Ahh yes, evolution my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [`gnome-pilot`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-pilot)  will allow you to sync your Palm to Evolution once you configure it (it's found in **System** > **Preferences** > **PalmOS Devices**). The first time you use gnome-pilot ("PalmOS Devices"), you will get a setup wizard like shown below. If you have issues, you may need to change the `Type:` and/or `Device:` settings; my setup is as shown below.

There are other sync programs (like JPilot) but gnome-pilot is the only one I know that can get your data into one of those programs.

[image: Setup Wizard page 1]

[image: Setup Wizard page 2]